# Controller testing Show page with Rspec, it gives an error nil & and render empty page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, tdd

I'm new to TDD on Rails, and I'm trying to test videos_controller with the book "Everyday Rails Testing with Rails" for simple show page but it gives me error 'nil' & render empty, as follows. But I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please advise me. Thank you for your help.

spec/controllers/videos_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe VideosController do
  describe "GET show" do
   before {@video1 = Video.create!(title: 'Family Guy', description: 'Some description')}

     it "assigns the requested video to the @video" do
      get :show, id: @video1
      assigns(:video).should == @video1
    end

    it "render show tempalte" do
      get :show, id: @video1
      response.should render_template :show
    end
  end
end
```

app/controllers/videos_controller.rb

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user  

  def show 
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Error I got in my terminal:

```
Failures:

  1) VideosController GET show assigns the requested video to the @video
     Failure/Error: assigns(:video).should == @video1
   expected: #<Video id: 1, title: "Family Guy", small_cover_url: nil, large_cover_url: nil, description: "Some description", created_at: "2013-05-13 00:12:32", updated_at: "2013-05-13 00:12:32">
        got: nil (using ==)
 # ./spec/controllers/videos_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) VideosController GET show render show tempalte
     Failure/Error: response.should render_template :show
   expecting <"show"> but rendering with <"">
 # ./spec/controllers/videos_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `before_filter` in controller

```
before_filter :require_user
```

You have not supplied the required action in the test, so the real action `show` has not been reached yet.

To fix, just add necessary action say creating user or login, before `get :show`